# Toggle show/hide on specific element with Vue.js (cdn)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js (cdn) and axios to get stuff from heroku and mlab.

I want to display some information from the objects in a list and I want each line to act like a
button or have some sort of onclick that displays more information from the same object below. like a drop down.

I tried the button v-on:click="visible = !visible"...
And that works but it toggles show/hide on all of the elements, as expected.

I want to be able to toggle show/hide on a single element in a list of many.

This is what I have:

**index.html**

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="list" v-for="drinks in rom">
        <button v-on:click="visible = !visible">{{ drinks.brand }}</button>

        <div class="hidden" v-show="!visible">
            <p> {{ drinks.comment }} </p>
        </div> 
    </div><!--list-->
    </div><!--app-->
```

**main.js**

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
    return {
        rom: null,
        visible: true
    }
},
mounted() {
    axios
        .get('******')
        .then(response => (this.rom  = response.data))
}})
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to declare rom as an array:

```
data() {
    return {
        rom: []
    }
},
```

Then you can add a `visible` property to each data item in your API response:

```
mounted() {
    axios
        .get('******')
        .then(response => (this.rom = response.data.map(drinks => {
                drinks.visible = true;
                return drinks;
            })
        ))
}})
```

Then you can use that `visible` property in each loop of your `v-for`:

```
<div class="list" v-for="drinks in rom">
    <button v-on:click="drinks.visible = !drinks.visible">{{ drinks.brand }}</button>

    <div class="hidden" v-show="!drinks.visible">
        <p> {{ drinks.comment }} </p>
    </div> 
</div><!--list-->
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a visible property to your drink object, and then

```
v-on:click="drink.visible = !drink.visible"
```

Or you can create an array mapped with your drink with the id as key, and true or false as value and then :

```
v-on:click="drinksVisibility[drink.id].visible = !drinksVisibility[drink.id].visible"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have a visible property in each object and render elements

```
rom : [{brand: 'drink1',visible: false,comment: 'drink1 - comment'},
  {brand: 'drink2',visible: false,comment: 'drink2 - comment'}]
```

then write a toggle function to show/hide an element by passing an index value to modify particular object visible value true/false

`<button v-on:click=toggle(index)>{{ drinks.brand }}</button>`

example : https://codepen.io/sandeep821/pen/YdxjWg